# Replace oldSchema with newSchema in functions

Tags: postgresql, import, export, pg-dump, pg-restore

I exported a database called *oldDatabase* using `pg_dump` in directory format.  This database contains a schema, tables and functions owned by *oldRole*.  These functions contain SQL statements like

```
INSERT INTO oldSchema.table(...)
```

To load *mydump/* into *newDatabase*, I followed these steps:

1. Create *oldRole* in my *newCluster* (to load without errors),
2. Load my dump into the *newDatabase* using this command:

   ```
   pg_restore mydump/ -d newDatabase
   ```
3. Reassign objects owned by *oldRole* to *newRole*,
4. Rename *oldSchema* to *newSchema*,
5. And drop *oldRole*.

But functions still contain statements like `INSERT INTO oldSchema.table(...)` and I get errors when I run these functions, because `oldSchema` does not exist.  I have to modify manually all functions to get `INSERT INTO newSchema.table(...)`.

Is there a best practice to load properly from a database to another database with different schema and owner names?  How to perform a correct mapping?

I use PostgreSQL v9.5 with Red Hat 7.

Comment: A: No.  Q: Why are you renaming one of the schemas in the database? is this related to the role name change?  use of dot in identifiers makes your question confusing.   `insert into xxx.yyy.zzz` is not valid SQL.

Comment: A: @Jasen oldSchema is renamed to newSchema because environment change between both clusters. And yes, role name were also changed for this reason. I modified the dot usage to avoid confusion.